# »Du hast Recht« oder »Du hast recht«?

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

It seems that the latter is the right one. But, the former one is more reasonably by grammar?

Anyway, it should be a noun.

Comment: You could easily look up this by entering "recht haben Duden" in your preferred search engine. - According to "Duden", both spellings (capital letter vs. small letter) are acceptable but recommended is "recht haben". This is also how it was obligatorily spelled previous to the so called Rechtschreibreform in the mid 1990. The traditional spellings - which still are considered better by some - had developped over centuries as good practice in professional typesetting. There must not always be a "logical" explanation.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=recht+haben+klein+oder+gro%C3%9F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions are correct, but there is a subtile difference in Meaning. So subtile, that most speakers are not aware of it, but I'll show you:

### Du hast Recht.

Here »*Recht*« is a noun, that you also could use with an article, but this is not usual in German:

> Du hast (*das*) **Recht.**
>   You have (*the*) **right.**

But in ...

### Du hast recht.

The word *recht* is an adjective in adverbial usage. Like almost all adjectives, you can use this adjective:

- **attributive**

  > Mach weiter so, du bist auf dem **rechten** Weg.
  >   Go on, you are on the **right** way.
- **predicative**

  > Es war nicht **recht**, ihn fortzujagen.
  >   It was not **right** to chase him away.
- **adverbial**

  > Du hast **recht.**
  >   You are **right.**

---

The recommended version is the lowercase version: »Du hast recht.« But both versions are correct.

Comment: Doch man kann sagen, Du hast (das) Recht, hier zu kommen. Ja?

Comment: @User26328: Ja, das kann man so sagen. Aber Vorsicht! »Du hast das Recht, **hier** zu kommen« bedeutet: »Du hast das Recht, hier einen Orgasmus zu haben.« Du meinst vermutlich: »Du hast das Recht, **hierher** zu kommen«. (»hier kommen« = to have an orgasm here. »hierher kommen« = to come here.) In der deutschen Sprache darf man Orte und Richtungen nicht verwechseln!